# Is this pattern characteristic of a specific type of graphics bug? - Screenshot

Tags: debugging, graphics

Not a pro at computer graphics. Is this pattern characteristic of a specific type of graphics bug? Or does it not give very much information at all?

[image: What's the Bug?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be limited to the green component. The blue hair and the red stripe in the background seem ok. What colour should the striped bits be?